# How can I order by a derived property in linq to sql?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a property called Total that is derived from other values on my data object.  When I try to use this property in an order by statement in linq to sql I get:  The member '...' has no supported translation to SQL.  Which makes sense but is there a work around for this scenario?  Thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "derived" - is that property part of your model or not?

Comment: @Broken: I believe he means it's a property that uses other properties in his model to generate a value.

Comment: It is in a partial class used to total a few other properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could invoke the query and than do your `OrderBy()` clause.

```
var items = context.Tables.ToList().OrderBy(x=>x.Total);
```

You can do this since after you invoke `.ToList()` you will be using linq to objects.

As Broken mentions this might not work in all cases, another possible solution would be to reproduce your total calculation in your `.Select()`

***note***, my syntax might be off a bit, dont have VS with me `:)`

```
var items = context.Tables.Select(t=> new {t.Item1, Total=(t.Price + t.Tax)})
                          .OrderBy(t=>t.Total);
```

Now granted with this type of projection you wont end up with a `Table` any more but might be an option.

Comment: This might not be an option if the query includes i.e. `Skip()` or `Take()`, otherwise you'd have to pull *all* records from the DB. +1 though because I can't come up with anything better. Also `AsEnumerable()` would be the more light-weight approach.